# Extends tag with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to use `extends tag` in order to simplify my `HTML files` and mainly not write several time the same things.

So I created a `Base.html` file and `Home.html` which are located in :

```
Etat_civil
|__Home
   |__templates
      |__Home.html
|__BirthCertificate
|__Identity
|__templates
   |__Base.html
```

This is my **Base.html** file :

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>
    </head>

    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.datasystems.fr/"> DatasystemsEC </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Home tab -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li>

                <!-- Individual form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Fiches Individuelles
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "home" %}"> Accueil des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "form" %}"> Création des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "searched" %}"> Consultation des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "edited" %}"> Edition des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "deleted" %}"> Suppression des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Birth form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BChome" %}"> Accueil des actes de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCform" %}"> Création d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Wedding form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Actes de Mariage
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de mariage </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Divorce form tab -->

                <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Actes de Divorce
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de divorce </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Death form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span> Actes de Décès
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de décès </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Connexion tab -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Me Connecter </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

</html>
```

And my **Home.html** file :

```
{% extends 'Base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- ############### -->
    <!-- Page principale -->
    <!-- ############### -->

        <p align="center"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"></p>
        <h2 align="center"> <font color="#0083A2"> Bienvenue sur la page d'accueil du logiciel DatasystemsEC </font></align></h2>

{% endblock content %}
```

I get correctly my base.html but nothing appears inside. I should see my Home.html file with a picture and a title right ?

Base.html is overwritting on my Home.html file ?

I can paste my settings.py file in order to see templates and static directories if you want, but I don't see where the problem is located.

Thank you !

Comment: Because I specified 2 template directories ? The first one is for Home.html and the second one is for Base.html. I wrote that in my settings.py file. But I didn't know that both files should be together in the same file.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi django's template engine will look up templates in all the directories defined in the TEMPLATE_DIRS (stopping at the first matching one) as well as in apps "templates" directories (depending on the configured template loaders, but that's the default configuration). IOW : templates do __not__ have to be in the same directories.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi It works with `{% extends 'Base.html' %}` It's because I miss to write empty `block content`. Thank to Bruno who solve my problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no "content" block in your base.html template, so obviously you cannot override it in "home.html". The idea is to use the base template to define the common page structure, with (usually empty) blocks as placeholders that the "concrete" templates will fill. IOW : you must add an empty "content" block in your base template where you want the content to appear ;)

Comment: Thank you Bruno ! I didn't know the exact process to do that ! I read a non-official Django documentation made by a user and it's false. It works now so Thank you ;)

Comment: @Valentin by all means avoid "unofficial" documents until you know enough about the language / framework / whatever to assess the document's quality and pertinence (a document may be correct but only for an outdated version of your language or framework...). Do the whole official django tutorial for your django version, then browse the whole to get an idea of what's available and where it's documented (no need to do a full sequential read here, just take a couple hours to browse the main chapters and whatever catch your attention, then come back for more details when you need them).

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I do. But to my mind, Django doc is not easily readable and that's why I miss some things and I ask questions when I don't find any other solution on Stackoverflow, ... Even if it's really easy to get the answer on this forum, previously there is a searching timelapse ;)